# Julia DataFrames: how do i export a DataFrame

Tags: dataframe, julia

If I've created a DataFrame `df`, how can I save / export this to my cwd as a .csv file? How can I read it back in? The current ReadTheDocs [link](http://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/io.html!) is broken.

Comment: As what? A csv?

Comment: Thanks, I've re-edited the questin. A .csv works. I was just looking for anything. Wasn't able to find on the docs since the link is broken

Comment: The documentation links on the [main repository](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataFrames.jl) point to http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After referencing Matt B's [link](http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/stable/man/io/#Importing-data-from-tabular-data-files-1!), I have an answer. Suppose `cwd` is `C:/Desktop/test0` and we want to send a DataFrame `df` to a .csv file called `output_write` in directory `test1` on the Desktop:

```
test = "test1"
if isdir("../$test") == 0
    mkdir("../$test")  # .. to move one folder up
 end
writetable("test_results/$test/output_write.csv",df)
```

Note that we could have used `mkdir("/$test")` to place the directory in our `cwd` and that `$` accesses the contents of the variable `test`, which is `"test1"`

Now to read it back in as `df_read`:

```
df_read = readtable("test_results/$test/output_write.csv")
```

Answer (score 8):

Currently it's better to use the `CSV.jl` package, it's simpler and more efficient in writing `DataFrames` to files.

Assuming that you already imported the `DataFrames` package and created the data frame `df`:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("CSV")

using CSV

# for writing
CSV.write("outputfile.csv",df)

# for reading
new_df = CSV.read("outputfile.csv")
```

The default delimiter is `,`, but it's easily changed with :

```
CSV.write("outputfile.csv",df,delim='\t')
```

Note that `delim` needs to be of type `Char` and not type `String`.

Comment: Is there a way to write the variable names in the first row of the CSV file?

Comment: If the variable names are the headers of the dataframe, then theyare written too, so you can access them easily by other programs, such as awk, gnuplot, etc.